# Global Function Parameter

Tags: c++, methods

I am building a stack using arrays (no std::vector allowed) and I must implement a global method that serves as a constructor. The input parameters are two iterators (begin and end) and I have to create a stack from those. The problem is that before i actually create the stack i have to check whether or not is empty. Since I can not pass the stack as a parameter, how am I supposed to call methods on that?

Here is my code:

```
template <typename IterT>       
void method(IterT begin, IterT end) {
    try {   
        if(!is_empty())
            make_empty();
        for(; begin!=end; ++begin) {
            push(static_cast<T>(*begin));       
        }
    }
    catch(...) {
        clear();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Obviously is not working, the methods is_empty(), make_empty(), push() and clear() needs something to work on.

My test method is:

```
int a[5] = {7, 2, 33, 4, 1111};
stack<int> sp;
sp.push(25);  //check if stack is made empty
sp.print();
sp.method(a, a+5);
sp.print();
```

Comment: if `begin == end` then there are no elements inbetween

Comment: @user463035818 no man, i am not asking wether or not the method is correct, i am asking how i should call methods on the stack if the stack is not a parameter in the method

Comment: btw your premises seem quite arbitrary. I can understand that you cannot use `std::vector`, but why does it have to be a free method that acts as constructor instead of a constructor? why cant you pass the stack to the method?

Comment: then the question is even more unclear than i initially thought ;). If you cannot pass the stack then you cannot call a method on it.

Comment: given the constraints there is no other way as to have `stack<int> sp` being a global variable.

Comment: @user463035818 it's an homework, I must do like that, otherwise i would've used std::vector

Comment: @Swordfish, I have to create that not on the main.cpp but in the class implementation

Comment: @man_o_war then your question is flawed. "I must implement a global method"

Comment: I vaguely suspect you don't understand the difference between a member function and a free function. Either way, the question is unclear.

Comment: As an aside, a function that creates a stack **should not be `void`**. It should return the created `stack`, rather than modifying some global state somewhere

Comment: On re-reading what this does, it's like [`assign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign). The simple thing is to *unconditionally* `clear` the stack. You don't need to avoid no-op corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

If it has to be global method that serves as a constructor then what you can do is:
inside `stack.h` class insert friend declaration for this global method like:

```
template <typename T>
class stack {
    template <typename U, typename IterIt>
    friend stack<U> construct(IterIt beg, IterIt end);

private:
    T* inside_;
};
```

In stack.cpp we can now define this construct method:

```
#include "stack.h"
#include <cstddef>
template <typename T, typename IterIt>
stack<T> construct(IterIt beg, IterIt end) {
    // warning: works only with iterators defining binary operator-
    stack<T> result;
    size_t elems = end - beg;
    result.inside_ = new T[elems];
    T* add_to = result.inside_;
    while (beg != end) {
        *add_to = *beg;
        ++add_to;
        ++beg;
    }
    return result;
}
```

And with simple main method you can have:

```
int main() {
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    stack<int> s = construct<int>(a, a + 5);
}
```

I hope this solves your problem. Remember, there might be some corner cases that you would need to solve, but as a baseline I think this should suffice.

Comment: You have to declare all the instantiations of `construct` in stack.cpp this way.

Comment: Yes, you are right with that. Although this design is very unnatural, so it's just better to use normal templated constructor :)